# I want a new array with values divisible by 3 or 5 only using boolean mask

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, boolean, numpy-ndarray

The below code gives out an error and I have no clue how else to get the desired output.

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
mask=(arr%3==0 or arr%5==0)
print(arr[mask])
```

***Output-*** *ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() at line 4*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy built in function for `or`:

```
mask=np.logical_or(arr%3==0,arr%5==0)
arr[mask]
#[ 0  3  5  6  9 10 12 15 18 20 21 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to be changed in your code:

1. You need to replace **and/or** with **&/|**
2. You have to add braces for conditions to make sure there is no ambiguity in evaluation.

Below is the updated code:

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
print(arr[(arr%3==0) | (arr%5==0)])
# Output: [ 0  3  5  6  9 10 12 15 18 20 21 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr%3==0 or arr%5==0`
ORing two boolean variables will give a boolean answer so it can't be used as an index. To get all values, here is a simple, readable code:

```
ans = []
for array in arr:
    for i in array:
        if i%3==0 or i%5==0:
            ans.append(i)
print(ans)
```